# What is the best way to reuse blocks of XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got many user controls like this:

**PageManageCustomers.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class PageManageCustomers : BasePage
{
 ...
}
```

which inherit from:

**PageBase.cs:**

```
public class BasePage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 ...
}
```

Since **PageBase.cs** has **no accompanying XAML file**, I have to put the XAML that it refers to in **each** of the user controls which inherit it, e.g. the following block is repeated in **every** XAML file of every control that inherits `PageBase`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="manageAreaCellTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
    Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Delete" MouseDown="System_Delete_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Text=" "/>
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
           Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Edit" MouseDown="System_Edit_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm trying to put this block into a **resource file** but can't get the syntax right, it says:

> 'ResourceDictionary' root element
>   requires a x:Class attribute to
>   support event handlers in the XAML
>   file. Either remove the event handler
>   for the MouseDown event, or add a
>   x:Class attribute to the root element.

Or perhaps I could read these blocks in with **XamlReader**` somehow?

**How can I put this repeated block of code in one place so that it is not repeated in every XAML file that inherits BagePage?**

## Here is a reproducable example of this problem:

**Window1.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestXamlPage8283.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainContent"/>
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestXamlPage8283
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Page1 page1 = new Page1();
            MainContent.Children.Add(page1);

            Page2 page2 = new Page2();
            MainContent.Children.Add(page2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Page1.xaml:**

```
<local:BasePage x:Class="TestXamlPage8283.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestXamlPage8283"
    Height="40" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTitle}"
                   FontSize="14"
                   FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBlock Text="This is XAML that is specific to page one." />
    </StackPanel>
</local:BasePage>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace TestXamlPage8283
{
    public partial class Page1 : BasePage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PageTitle = "Page One";
        }
    }
}
```

**Page2.xaml:**

```
<local:BasePage x:Class="TestXamlPage8283.Page2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestXamlPage8283"
    Height="40" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTitle}"
                   FontSize="14"
                   FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBlock Text="This is XAML that is specific to page two." />
    </StackPanel>
</local:BasePage>
```

**Page2.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace TestXamlPage8283
{
    public partial class Page2 : BasePage
    {
        public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PageTitle = "Page Two";
        }
    }
}
```

**BasePage.cs:**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestXamlPage8283
{
    public class BasePage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region ViewModelProperty: PageTitle
        private string _pageTitle;
        public string PageTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return _pageTitle;
            }

            set
            {
                _pageTitle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PageTitle");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public BasePage()
        {
            DataContext = this;
        }

        #region INotifiedProperty Block
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**How do I take *this* block**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTitle}"
           FontSize="14"
           FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

***out* of Page1.xaml and Page2.xaml and put it in *one* place so I can *refer* to it from Page1.xaml and Page2.xaml?** (so that when I want to change FontSize=14 to FontSize=16, I just have to change it in one place)

Comment: It seems what you're asking is something similar to Asp.net's master pages. I don't know if that's possible. For your TextBlock last sample (changing the FontSize of the PageTitle textblock), isn't that what styles are for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use resource dictionaries - add a `MyDictionary.xaml` file to your project, setting its Build Action to "Page":

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="manageAreaCellTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
              Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Delete" MouseDown="System_Delete_Click"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" "/>
            <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
              Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Edit" MouseDown="System_Edit_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in other XAML files you refer to it with:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyDictionary.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    ... some other local resources ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and refer to your resource as `Template={StaticResource manageAreaCellTemplate}`.

Comment: When I do this it tells me: "'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file. Either remove the event handler for the MouseDown event, or add a x:Class attribute to the root element." when I add the x:Class attribute, I get errors like this: "Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'TestApp.Pages.BasePageManageItems'; another partial declaration of this type exists"

Comment: That's right you have `MouseDown` events that cannot be bound at compile time as the dictionary has no code behind.
You should either add event handlers at runtime or use commands: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx.